# Uploading text data to server from SQLite is faster or text files?

Tags: android, sqlite

My application receives a lot of data every milliseconds(name,id,value,.. of a signal from a simulator device). and I should upload this data to MySQL server. First I need to save them in a database and upload them to the server via GSM network. The reason that I save data into the mobile device is that the connection is so slow and the app receives a quite large number of data at a time and cannot upload them at once, also it may encounter disconnection problem. In fact, I just need a temporary storage and I don't want to do any data manipulation in the SQLite. Currently I am writing the data to the simple text file (CSV) and then upload every 20 lines to the server using name/value pairs in Android HttpPost, but what about SQLite? Is it faster to insert data to SQLite and then upload it? Which approach is preferable?

Here is the sample data that I receive from the simulator device:

time,id,name,value

143125738714,id1,name1,8.000004

143125738715,id2,name2,0.0

Answer (score 1):

Most preferably use SQLite DB to save the data and then send to the server.
When you use file handling then,

1. you have to read all file to the buffer and then again get 20 lines
   from the buffer which is pretty heavy(means lots of work) also,
2. After sending some lines(data) to the server you need to keep track
   of sent lines(data) or you need to delete those lines(data) from
   your files (again lots of work).

By using SQLite it is easy to read records(lines) and delete records(lines).

Also in order to send data to server, send data line by line(instead of sending bunch of lines) so you can keep the record of sent data (lines) in case of network disconnected inbetween.

**UPDATE :**

If you want to send data by extracting id, name etc. and also to delete sent lines then, use SQLite( because extraction of data and deletion is efficient in SQLite)

If you want to send just lines without any extraction of data and also not to delete sent lines then just use .txt files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, for me just the speed is important. In fact, I read 20 lines from the file and insert them to a list of name value pairs and upload them to server. then I read next 20 lines and don't need to delete previous lines! If you just want to consider the speed of uploading part, which one is faster? reading from a csv file or reading from a SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using simple text file. But, if the text file accumulates a huge mass of lines without deleting, you may need a lot of seek time to reach the latest 20 lines. In this case, you have better to keep the file pointer without closing the file, or control the file size with serialized file names.